# What are the available options for collecting recurring payments in India?

Tags: payment-gateway, payment-processing, recurring-billing

I'm considering 2checkout with chargebee. Is there a better option ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2CO are decent. There's also BlueSnap and of course - PayPal.

Answer (score 0):

Bluesnap has subscription services built in, plus shopper support.